# What if I didn't finish my last master's degree on time prior to the starting of a new program?

Tags: masters, application

I'm doing a Master's degree currently and hoping to graduate in Spring 2023.
Given that now I want to apply for another Master's degree that starts in Fall 2023, I'd like to use my current university as the main institute for the application.

I just wonder what if I get accepted but didn't successfully finish my current master's degree on time (prior to the starting of my next master's program)? Can I still enrol my new master's program without a hitch? Or what am I supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "the main institute for the application"? Presumably the education section of your CV would indicate you've earned a Bachelors degree (or equivalent) at some institution, and that you've taken courses towards a Masters degree at another. Will you claim in your application that you have completed or will complete your masters degree?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the rules of the new institution. We can't know or give advice on what that might be. Talk to them as the issue firms up.

Comment: The key point is when applying for another master's degree, I put my current master's degree on cv. But prior to the start of the new program, I didn't finish the previous masters program (which I put on my education experience in my application). I ask this because it seems one should successfully graduate from his previous program before starting the next program.

Answer (score 2):

You should not put a degree on your CV/application that you have not earned - this is fraudulent.

It's perfectly reasonable to put an in-progress degree program on your CV/application *as a degree in-progress*, where it is clear you have not yet earned the degree, and indicate the date you expect to earn the degree. For example:

> University of Great Things, MS in-progress, anticipated Spring 2023

You should only indicate that you expect to get this degree *if you do expect to get it*. If not, you can mention the coursework but don't write you plan to get the degree.

If you are accepted to a program but there has been a major change since your application, such as not obtaining a degree that you previously said you would obtain, I think the best thing to do would be to contact that institution and let them know about the change. At that point, it's up to them. For another masters program, I think it's unlikely they would change their decision since a first masters degree is not typically a requirement for another masters program (that would certainly make it difficult to ever obtain the first one), but they might.